# Double curved arrow

Tags: symbols, arrows, amssymb, arrow-curve

I found out that `amssymb` has double arrow the code is `$\rightleftarrows$`.

**My question is:** do we have a command *for double curve arrow*, that the one above is concave down (the arrow is from left to right) and the one below is concave up (the arrow is right to left)?

In case we do not have it. Can we make it and used it as a single code?

Below is a pic of the kind of curved arrow I am looking for.
[image]

Comment: You might try your luck on [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: You might draw something using `tikz` and define a command for that...

Comment: I thought about that, but I have limited using to tiki. if possible give me more idea about it. or you can post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following doesn't look too bad, imho:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand*\curvedrightleft{%
  \mathrel{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]%
      \draw[->] (0,0.05) to [out=30,in=150] (1,0.05);%
      \draw[->] (1,-0.05) to [out=-150,in=-30] (0,-0.05);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
$A \curvedrightleft B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect answer for my question.

Answer (score 7):

There are matching symbols in `mathabx`, which only have to be stacked on top of each other.  It can be easily made to look decent in all sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\curvearrowleft}    {\mathrel}{mathb}{"F0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\curvearrowbotright}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"F4}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\curvearrowleftbotright{%
  \mathord{\mathpalette\@curvearrowleftbotright\relax}%
}
\newcommand\@curvearrowleftbotright[2]{%
  \raisebox{.3ex}{$#1\m@th\curvearrowleft$}%
  \llap{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1\m@th\curvearrowbotright$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  A \curvearrowleftbotright B_{A \curvearrowleftbotright B_{A \curvearrowleftbotright B}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \mathcal{K}_3 = V / \curvearrowleftbotright = \{ \bar{B}_1, \bar{B}_2, \dotsc \}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt to combine the advantages of Henri Menke's answer (automatic scaling) and Skillmon's answer (flexibility of Ti*k*z). The basic idea is to scale the picture according to the width of a reference character (here A), and to use `\mathchoice`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand*\curvedrightleft{%
\ifmmode\mathchoice{\mathrel{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=height("A")/0.45cm]%
      \draw[->] (0,0.05) to [out=30,in=150] (1,0.05);%
      \draw[->] (1,-0.05) to [out=-150,in=-30] (0,-0.05);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}  
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=height("A")/0.4cm]%
      \draw[->] (0,0.05) to [out=30,in=150] (1,0.05);%
      \draw[->] (1,-0.05) to [out=-150,in=-30] (0,-0.05);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
{\mathrel{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=height("A")/0.6cm]%
      \draw[->] (0,0.05) to [out=30,in=150] (1,0.05);%
      \draw[->] (1,-0.05) to [out=-150,in=-30] (0,-0.05);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
{\mathrel{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=height("A")/0.8cm]%
      \draw[->] (0,0.05) to [out=30,in=150] (1,0.05);%
      \draw[->] (1,-0.05) to [out=-150,in=-30] (0,-0.05);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=height("A")/0.4cm]%
      \draw[->] (0,0.05) to [out=30,in=150] (1,0.05);%
      \draw[->] (1,-0.05) to [out=-150,in=-30] (0,-0.05);%
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi
}
\begin{document}
$A \curvedrightleft B$ 

$X_{A \curvedrightleft B_{A \curvedrightleft B}}$ 

{\tiny A \curvedrightleft B}

{\Large A \curvedrightleft B}

\end{document}
```

[image]